# Material Swipe To Dismiss in Jetpack Compose with a Column instead of a LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, swipe-gesture

In my Jetpack Compose project I want to use Material SwipeToDismiss to delete an item with a swipe. In my composable I use a Column in a list instead of a LazyColumn. The problem is that when the item is deleted a recomposition starts and all following items are also deleted (because the dismissState seems to be the same for the next item). For example if the Column has 7 items and I delete item #5 then also item #6 and item #7 gets deleted.

It works if I use a LazyColumn (probably because of the keys) with a fixed height but I just want a list of items without scrolling or a fixed height. Any suggestions how to get this running?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
private fun DocumentationsList(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    task: DBTask,
    documentations: List<DBDocumentation>,
    onDocumentationDelete: (DBDocumentation) -> Unit,
) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        for ((index, documentation) in documentations.withIndex()) {

            var dismissState = rememberDismissState(initialValue = DismissValue.Default)
            if (dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)) {
                onDocumentationDelete(documentation)
            }

            SwipeToDismiss(
                state = dismissState,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp),
                directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
                dismissThresholds = { direction ->
                    FractionalThreshold(if (direction == DismissDirection.StartToEnd) 0.25f else 0.5f)
                },
                background = {
                    val direction = dismissState.dismissDirection ?: return@SwipeToDismiss
                    val color by animateColorAsState(
                        when (dismissState.targetValue) {
                            DismissValue.Default -> Color.LightGray
                            DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> Color.Green
                            DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                        }
                    )
                    val alignment = when (direction) {
                        DismissDirection.StartToEnd -> Alignment.CenterStart
                        DismissDirection.EndToStart -> Alignment.CenterEnd
                    }
                    val icon = when (direction) {
                        DismissDirection.StartToEnd -> Icons.Default.Done
                        DismissDirection.EndToStart -> Icons.Default.Delete
                    }
                    val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                        if (dismissState.targetValue == DismissValue.Default) 0.75f else 1f
                    )

                    Box(
                        Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color).padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
                        contentAlignment = alignment
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            icon,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description",
                            modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                        )
                    }
                },
                dismissContent = {
                    Card(
                        elevation = animateDpAsState(
                            if (dismissState.dismissDirection != null) 4.dp else 0.dp
                        ).value
                    ) {
                        
                        // Layout here
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`key`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#key(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)) which will work the same `LazyColumn` `key` parameter:

```
Column(
    modifier = modifier
) {
    for ((index, documentation) in documentations.withIndex()) {
        key(uniqueKey) {
            // your view
        }
    }
}
```

This should not be your `index`, as it will change for all items below the deleted one after deletion, it should be some identifier unique to each item in your collection.